# Oracle SQL trying to limit rows per day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query which returns 132 rows per day  but i only need 24 rows out of the query per day. How could i limit the query?

```
select forecast_date
, extract(month from forecast_date) as month_no
,forecast_hour
,indice
,sum(load) as eere_tuta_33
from 23_table_jorde 
where indice = 'eere' and rownum <= '24' and forecast_date = '01-jan-2017'
group by forecast_date, forecast_hour , load , indice
```

Comment: Use an ORDER BY clause to specify which 24 rows to return.

Comment: Then use `FETCH FIRST 24 ROWS ONLY`.

Comment: Also, remove load from the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: the way you mentioned works but i guess my problem is different  I need to remove duplicates on forecast_hour  instead of limiting it to 24 rows. My hour should go from 1 to 24 and stop there but it repeats itself 4-5 times more

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Exactly; without sample data, it is more or less pointless trying to guess what you did wrong (why are there forecast columns for date and time? What is their datatype?  Looking at code you posted, it looks as if forecast_date is VARCHAR2 (as you compared it to a string), but I presume it is just a common mistake that doesn't reflect real situation). Etc. So - have a look at what jarlh said in a previous comment.